# No response from $.post WordPress ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

I have a form which I am trying to submit and receive data via WordPress AJAX.

I get no errors in the console but I also do not get any of the logging within the `.post` function

Live link (form under price): http://e390b6a4.ngrok.io//product/test-product-1/

Javascript:

```
function checkZipInstall(zipCode) {
console.log(zipCode);
    jQuery.post(rzcc_ajax_script.ajaxurl, zipCode
    ,
        function(response_from_rzcc_action_function){
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response_from_rzcc_action_function);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.install_possible);
            if(response.install_possible === "true") {
                console.log('true');
            } else {
                console.log('false');
                //window.location.replace(response.redirect_url);
            }



        }
    );
}

jQuery('#vehicle-group').repeater({
    btnAddClass: 'r-btnAdd',
    btnRemoveClass: 'r-btnRemove',
    groupClass: 'r-group',
    minItems: 1,
    maxItems: 0,
    startingIndex: 0,
    showMinItemsOnLoad: true,
    reindexOnDelete: true,
    repeatMode: 'append',
    animation: 'fade',
    animationSpeed: 400,
    animationEasing: 'swing',
    clearValues: true
});

/* Prevent Add Button Refreshing */
jQuery( ".repeater-add-btn" ).click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

jQuery('#product_form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData3 = jQuery(this).serializeJSON();

    checkZipInstall(formData3);

});
```

**Solved**

As suggested by @charlietfl I needed to include an `action` parameter to the request. Updated function here:

```
function checkZipInstall(zipCode) {
    jQuery.post(rzcc_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
        {
            'action': 'the_ajax_hook',
            'zipCode': zipCode['zipCode']
        },
        function(response_from_rzcc_action_function){
            response = jQuery.parseJSON(response_from_rzcc_action_function);
            console.log(response);
            console.log(response.install_possible);
            if(response.install_possible === "true") {
                console.log('true');
            } else {
                console.log('false');
                //window.location.replace(response.redirect_url);
            }



        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network. is there an `action` field and a `nonce` in form?

Comment: Also probably should be using `serlalize()`

Comment: @charlietfl Looking at the network panel it says 400 bad request. There isn't an `action` field in there (I have used this function previously and this also didn't include an `action` field however it did work without). No nonce, but using it from within WordPress so the cookies are passed, so should still work?

Comment: To be honest I haven't worked in wordpress for a few years. Just remember that the admin ajax api usually needs an `action`

Comment: Did you add your ajax action in functions.php? Further you didn't insert an action. Please read more here https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Adding the action worked, thank you @charlietfl. A good reminder!

Comment: @BenH it's also a good behavior to vote up who helped you ;-)